# Dictionary with class as Key

Tags: c#, class, dictionary, key

I have measured data and I would like to store it in a 2 dimensional way. I thought I could make a `Dictionary` like this:

```
Dictionary<Key, string> dic = new Dictionary<Key, string>();
```

"Key" here is my a own class with two int variables. Now I want to store the data in this `Dictionary` but it doesn't work so far. If I want to read the data with the special Key, the error report says, that the Key is not available in the `Dictionary`.

Here is the class Key:

```
public partial class Key
{
    public Key(int Bahn, int Zeile) {
    myBahn = Bahn;
    myZeile = Zeile;

}
    public int getBahn()
    {
        return myBahn;
    }
    public int getZeile()
    {
        return myZeile;
    }
    private  int myBahn;
    private int myZeile;
}
```

for testing it I made something like this:

Getting elements in:

```
Key KE = new Key(1,1);
dic.Add(KE, "hans");
...
```

Getting elements out:

```
Key KE = new Key(1,1);
monitor.Text = dic[KE];
```

Has someone an idea?

Comment: Why not use string as key? What exactly you are trying to store in dictionary? Can you explain  the use case?

Comment: Yes. I have data from an 3D Room Scanner. The Scanner has two Axis. I would like to store the messurement depending on the position of the two Axis. So if Axis one is at position 15 and Axis two at position 30 i would like to have the Key: 15,30

Comment: And what do you store in the string value?

Comment: This is just for testing. I have an other class where 4 double values are stored. This will be the data wich i want to store as value of the dictionary.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible but there's many easy workaround (ex: use the class name as key)

Comment: Okay, let me try to do this a little more specifically: 
A dict type, is a set. A key, that must be UNIQUE, and then anything you want as a "value". 

every instance you create of KE must be unique. 
there are instances where even the accept solution will fail. 

if you create two identical instances, even their "json" string, will result in the same hash.
You can make an ID on the instance, that is set by something like a factory pattern? or you can make the system unable to make instances that are identical, depending on your needs. 
but modifying how dict works to solve this is bad.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to override methods `GetHashCode` and `Equals` in your own class to use it as a key.

```
class Foo 
{ 
    public string Name { get; set;} 
    public int FooID {get; set;}
    public override int GetHashCode()             
    {  
           return FooID; 
    }
     public override bool Equals(object obj) 
    { 
             return Equals(obj as Foo); 
    }

    public bool Equals(Foo obj)
     { 
          return obj != null && obj.FooID == this.FooID; 
     }
}
```

Comment: thank you. But i can not implement it in my class.. Can you explain what happens if i overwrite these methods? And How would it be if you have two int variables in yout Foo Class? like:                                             
                                                                                                             class Foo 
{ 
public int Name { get; set;} 
public int FooID {get; set;}

Comment: By default `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods from `object` class are called in order to compare  a key against the value you are searching in the dictionary. This will not give you the desired results as comparison won't happen according to your custom class. When you override these methods, you can customise the way the above said comparison happens. Just return a value from `GetHashCode` that makes the object unique and do the equality check inside `Equals` for all the properties of your class

Comment: Here is an implementation https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23610/Dictionary-with-a-Custom-Key

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of an alternate opinion, and not to be disparaging of Mr. Kuroi's solution (which is a good one), here is a simple class that can be used as a key in a map as well as other uses. We use a complex class as a key because we want to track other things. In this example, we arrive at a vertex in a graph and we want to know if we have visited it before.

```
public class Vertex : IComparable<Vertex>, IEquatable<Vertex>, IComparable
{
    String m_strVertexName = String.Empty;
    bool m_bHasVisited = false;

    public Vertex()
    {
    }

    public Vertex(String strVertexName) : this()
    {
        m_strVertexName = strVertexName;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return m_strVertexName;
    }

    public string VertexName
    {
        get { return m_strVertexName; }
        set
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                m_strVertexName = value; 
        }
    }

    public bool HasVisited
    {
        get { return m_bHasVisited; }
        set { m_bHasVisited = value; }
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ToString().GetHashCode();
    }
    public int CompareTo(Vertex rhs)
    {
        if (Equals(rhs))
            return 0;
        return ToString().CompareTo(rhs.ToString());
    }
    int IComparable.CompareTo(object rhs)
    {
        if (!(rhs is Vertex))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("CompareTo: Not a Vertex");
        return CompareTo((Vertex)rhs);
    }
    public static bool operator < (Vertex lhs, Vertex rhs) => lhs.CompareTo(rhs) < 0;
    public static bool operator > (Vertex lhs, Vertex rhs) => lhs.CompareTo(rhs) > 0;
    public bool Equals (Vertex rhs) => ToString() == rhs.ToString();
    public override bool Equals(object rhs)
    {
        if (!(rhs is Vertex))
            return false;
        return Equals((Vertex)rhs);
    }
    public static bool operator == (Vertex lhs, Vertex rhs) => lhs.Equals(rhs);
    public static bool operator != (Vertex lhs, Vertex rhs) => !(lhs == rhs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you could use a class as key by implementing your own `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, I would not advise to do it if you're not yet familiar with C#.

These methods will be invoked by C# internal libraries, which expect them to work exactly as per specification, handling all edge cases gracefully. If you put a bug in them, you might be in for an unpleasant head scratching session.

In my opinion, it would be no less efficient and way simpler to create a key on the spot using tried, true and tested existing types that already support hashing and comparison.

From your angular coordinates, e.g.:

```
int Bahn = 15;
int Zeile = 30;
```

You could use a string (e.g. `"15,30"`):

```
String Key (int Bahn, int Zeile) { return $"{Bahn},{Zeile}"; }

var myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
myDict.Add (Key(Bahn,Zeile), myString);
```

or a two elements tuple (e.g. `<15,30>`) if you need something more efficient:

```
Tuple<int,int> Key (int Bahn, int Zeile) { return Tuple.Create(Bahn,Zeile); }

var myDict = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, string>();
myDict.Add (Key(Bahn,Zeile), myString);
```

or a mere combination of your two angles if the range is small enough to fit into an int (e.g. `15+30*360`) if you need something even more efficient:

```
int Key (int Bahn, int Zeile) { return Bahn+360*Zeile; }

var myDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
myDict.Add (Key(Bahn,Zeile), myString);
```

That seems a lot less cumbersome than:

```
   class Key {
      // truckloads of code to implement the class,
      // not to mention testing it thourougly, including edge cases
   }

    var myDict = new Dictionary<Key, string>();
    myDict.Add (new Key(Bahn,Zeile), myString);
```

### Mutability of the key

Also, note that your keys must be immutable as long as they are used to index an entry.

If you change the value of `Bahn` or `Ziel` after the key has been used to add an element, you will mess up your dictionary something bad.

The behaviour is undefined, but you will most likely lose random entries, cause memory leaks and possibly crash with an exception if the internal libraries end up detecting an inconsistent state (like several entries indexed by the same key).

For instance:

```
var myKey = new Key(15, 30);

for (String data in row_of_data_sampled_every_10_degrees)
{
   myDict.Add (myKey, data); // myKey must remain constant until the entry is removed
   myKey.Bahn += 10;         // changing it now spells the death of your dictionary
}
```

### A side note on hashing angular coordinates

Now the catch is, the generic hashing functions provided for ints, strings and tuples are unlikely to produce optimal results for your specific set of data.

I would advise to start with a simple solution and only resort to specialized code if you run into actual performance issues. In which case you would probably be better off using a data structure more suited to spatial indexing (typically a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) in case of polar coordinates, or an [octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) if you want to reconstruct a 3D model from your scanner data).

Comment: I would really encourage the prior solution as it teaches proper techniques and will be future proof.  I'm not sure that a one off is going to be future proof.  My suggestion is to use tried and true collections and techniques to allow a fancy, complicated class to be equatable and comparable like a primitive.

Comment: The OP example looks like a solution looking for a problem to me, and a dangerous one at that. "Using class as key" is a bad idea to begin with, so I'd rather challenge the very idea than go on about the usual IEquatable overloads.

Comment: Using a class as a key is very robust and has many applications.  Besides that, it is a good CS exercise to learn how to write complex classes that can act like primitives for operations like sorting, comparing, and sometimes even other operator overloading.  This technique is very popular in C++ when you want to create classes that can work seamlessly with the standard template library.  Like you say, your mileage may vary.

Comment: In the OP example it's a recipe for disaster, in my opinion. Anyway...